# Expected number of steps

Tags: mathematics, probability

There are N cars that are parked in N parking spots numbered from 1 to N. After the Nth parking spot, there are N more parking spots numbered from N+1 to 2N. At each step, a car is selected randomly and if the parking spot just ahead of it is empty, then it will move to the next parking spot with probability 1/2. What is the expected number of steps till all cars occupy the spots N+1 to 2N?

I tried using markov chains to solve this. Each state in the chain will be represented as (i,N-i), where i is the number of cars in the parking spots from 1 to N and n-i are the cars in the spots N+1 to 2N.
State (0,N) will be the absorbing state. Using this I tried finding the expected number of steps to reach (0,N) from (N,0).

Comment: If you are looking for a purely mathematical approach, you may consider posting this on Maths.SE. Although it is not off-topic here. I expect 4*N^2 < E(nb_steps) < 2*N^3.

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: From the description it sounds like a car in slot $i$ moves to slot $i+1$, but from your state space it sounds like a car in slot $i$ moves to slot $i+N$. In the latter interpretation, does "a car is selected randomly" mean from among all $N$ cars or just the ones that haven't yet moved?

Comment: The state space is such that the state changes when a car moves from the Nth spot to the N+1th spot and also, any car can be selected from all the N cars

Comment: The states are such that each state (i,N-i) can transition to the state (i-1,n-i+1) or can remain in the same state. What i assumed, taking your example, the state(0,1,1,0) can transition to the state(0,0,1,1) only when the state's configuration changes to (0,1,0,1). This will be handled by transitioning to the same state.

Comment: Your state needs to track the actual locations of the cars, not just the count among the first $N$ spots. For $N=2$, the following are different situations and need to be distinguished from each other: $(0,1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1,0)$. The first state requires only one move, but the second state requires two because the car in spot 2 is blocked by the car in spot 3.

Comment: I don’t see how you can merge the states in the way you have proposed. I recommend working it out for $N=2$ with the $\binom42=6$ states rather than your $3$ states.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766082/expected-number-of-steps-to-move-all-cars-to-their-new-spots

Answer (score 3):

Here are the first $10$ values, obtained via a Markov chain with $\binom{2N}{N}$ states, one for each placement of $N$ cars in $2N$ spots:
\begin{matrix}
N & \text{expected number} \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\
2 & 14 \\
3 & 39.125 \\
4 & 78.178269319 \\
5 & 131.55549073 \\
6 & 199.50383036 \\
7 & 282.19557982 \\
8 & 379.75904678 \\
9 & 492.29418149 \\
10 & 619.88144334 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: I get the [same values](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFBbsMgEFSvvGKVE9hYLTlVllz1lGM-EEUVcpaG2ICFsUTe0ksu7Z_a1xSHxFX3tDOzOzuCj6_hHI7OXi6fU1DV889DobwzoCbbBuf6EbQZnA_Q--mtle0RSda9bIN2dtE3N4KQ12WUbp1FRg6owGNLA6sJpDLQQI824SscE7xv03VhMntK7NO1U85DxyNoC2gng14GXLzm0griy-kPZ9OyyUd3dbcvaawEZ2XYdaWo92wZxX7E_4sGqgbEQs0xYpmxxzB5myakPcD4aEh-su_tnFDP-by070gFF-IWL0JOQYssab4uNOMsJxi8toFGvmpWXPVOpj4p2fX-Ib8).

Comment: I get the same with my simulation.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer** - Simulation

Welcome to this site @12HackingEarth.

Those assumptions are made in the simulation (If I understood correctly your challenge):

- Any car can be selected, independently of its position.
- If a car that cannot move to their right is selected (ie. last slot, or adjacent slot occupied), a step is counted, but the state does not change.

The runnable code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ygz6h49e/).

It computes expected values and standard deviation from N = 1 to 100 over 300 simulation for each N.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/0Bf3qTbg) is an output of the simulation as csv you can play around.

First 10 values:

> N,ExpectedValue,Standard Deviation 
> 1, 2.07, 1.52 
> 2, 14.3, 6.45 
> 3, 39.58, 12.58 
> 4, 78.98, 19.71 
> 5, 130.85, 26.66 
> 6, 200.25, 39.85 
> 7, 280.22, 48.6 
> 8, 379.94, 60.09 
> 9, 493.68, 59.42 
> 10, 615.67, 76.79